# Visual Basic Textbox Content Restrictions

Tags: vb.net

How can I restrict a textbox to only accept lowercase letters with one uppercase letter, or at least 1 uppercase letter and a number?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Also, please use titles that have something to do with the actual question.

Comment: @EdCottrell I really like that link.  Thanks for posting it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: sorry im just new to visual basic
the problem is i want when you input a password in the textbox the a pop up message will appear  say that i must input lowercase and uppercase and number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a string contains at least one upper character, one lower character and one number, you can use the Char.[IsUpper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isupper(v=vs.110).aspx) / [IsLower](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.islower(v=vs.110).aspx) / [IsNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y(v=VS.110).aspx) methods.

```
Private Function IsValidPasswordFormat(ByVal text As String) As Boolean
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) Then
        Return False
    End If

    If text.Any(Function(c) Char.IsUpper(c)) AndAlso
        text.Any(Function(c) Char.IsLower(c)) AndAlso
        text.Any(Function(c) Char.IsNumber(c)) Then
        Return True
    End If

    Return False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose that `str` is the textbox.text

```
Dim ucount as integer
ucount=0
For Each c As Char In str
    Dim charCode As Integer = AscW(c)
    If charCode >= 65 AndAlso charCode < 91 Then
        ucount += 1
    End If
Next
if ucount>1
    'do something
End If
```

In the do `something` part, for example you can put `textbox.text=""`